# Reasoning for failure to reject $H_0$

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

Following up on [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468486/using-anova-function-in-r-to-determine-whether-factors-have-same-effect/468490#468490), I would like to make an intuitive explanation of why i'm failing to reject $H_0$ ie that all varieties of wheat have same effect on yield. So, here is a boxplot:

[image]

And here is the model for it (without a global intercept):

```
lm=lm(yield~0+factor(variety)+clay+I(rainfall-mean(rainfall)))
```

Here is the summary for it:

```
Call:
lm(formula = yi ~ 0 + factor(va) + clay + I(ra - mean(ra)))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4685 -1.1002 -0.0688  1.3723  3.2639 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
factor(va)A      13.44778    0.63204  21.277  < 2e-16 ***
factor(va)B      12.57547    0.63234  19.887  < 2e-16 ***
factor(va)C      12.40505    0.60899  20.370  < 2e-16 ***
factor(va)D      12.59439    0.61368  20.523  < 2e-16 ***
clay             -1.97900    0.63081  -3.137  0.00351 ** 
I(ra - mean(ra))  0.05549    0.04209   1.318  0.19622    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.832 on 34 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9811,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9777 
F-statistic: 293.5 on 6 and 34 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

My reasoning of why i'm failing to reject $H_0 : \mu_A=\mu_B=\mu_C=\mu_D$
So, by looking at the means and boxplot, they have the same yield averagely, and A has a bit higher average. But the fact that A has a slightly higher average doesn't justify the rejection of $H_0$.

Would this be right?

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: yi
                 Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
factor(va)        3   5.607  1.8689  0.5569 0.647109   
clay              1  30.875 30.8753  9.1996 0.004612 **
I(ra - mean(ra))  1   5.833  5.8326  1.7379 0.196218   
Residuals        34 114.109  3.3561
```

Comment: You’re getting $p<2.2\times 10^{-16}$, which is about as small of a number as R can give.

Comment: @Dave this confirms my reasoning, right?

Comment: No, we want small p-values in order to reject. Yours is about as small as it can be. I don’t totally follow your regression, however. Which value(s) do you see as your p-value(s)?

Comment: @Dave I'm looking at the values for factor(va)A,factor(va)B and C and D. The seem to have same averages and similar t values. So  I think that they have similar effect on the model

Comment: The plot and the data summary don’t seem to agree

Comment: Pairwise comparisons are a separate issue. You have strong evidence against your claim that the factor groups all have the same mean.

Comment: @Dave I edited my question with the anova table. Doesn't this support my claim?

Comment: Please stop doing this without an intercept. Basically everyone uses an intercept in ANOVA, and it makes it hard to communicate when you omit it.